# Validating Mongo collections

Tags: ruby

I figure there is a better way that I should be doing this:

```
if !db.collection_names.include?("reports".to_s)
  db.create_collection("reports")
end

if !db.collection_names.include?("days".to_s)
  db.create_collection("days")
end

if !db.collection_names.include?("users".to_s)
  db.create_collection("users")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, firstly: `"string".to_s` is entirely redundant. That's already a `String`, so converting it again is just wasting your (processor's) time.

Secondly, writing `if` blocks with just one line and no `else` wastes a good deal of vertical real estate. I'd recommend that instead of

```
if condition
  statement
end
```

you should write

```
statement if condition
```

Ruby has `unless` as the opposite to `if`, and when you find yourself writing `if !...`, it's better to use `unless ...` instead. This is mostly because of convention -- Ruby programmers use `unless` a lot more, so it's quicker to parse.

As for shortening the method calls themselves, you could just pass `strict: false` in with the name, so each individual call becomes more like this:

```
db.create_collection('name', strict: false)
```

Then you don't need the condition at all.

Then, since you have three objects on which you want to perform the same action, you can put them in an array:

```
['reports', 'days', 'users']
```

(or use the fancier `%w{ reports days users }`, like I do below, but you'll want to read up on its gotchas first)

Then we can loop through that array:

```
%w{ reports days users }.each do |name|
  #...
end
```

And in place of `#...` we put the code to create the table:

```
db.create_collection(name, strict: false)
```

Or, if you don't want to rely on swallowing errors:

```
db.create_collection(name) unless db.collection_names.include?(name)
```

If we put that all together, it becomes this:

```
%w{ reports days users }.each do |name|
  db.create_collection(name) unless db.collection_names.include?(name)
end
```

Now, to add a collection, all you have to do is add it to the list. For example, if you wanted to add one called "years", add `years` in to the `%w`:

```
%w{ reports days users years }.each do |name|
  db.create_collection(name) unless db.collection_names.include?(name)
end
```